# Cannot interact with Youtube via keyboard

Tags: windows, youtube, microsoft-edge

I am using Microsoft Edge to browse Youtube. Normally I can use F key to full screen the youtube tab. However, if I alt tab to another app, then alt tab back to Youtube, then I cannot interact with youtube via keyboard (pressing F will not change to full screen) until I click the cursor onto Edge.

However, hotkeys for Edge itself still works normally, i.e. pressing Ctrl+W can still close a tab. Interaction with Youtube on Firefox still works normally (I can still press F to change to full screen).

Anyone knows what the problem is, and how to fix it?

Comment: I managed to replicate the problem with Edge, although sometimes it randomly doesn't happen. I noticed also that switching to another tab and back in Edge also fixes the problem. Looks like a bug in Edge.

Comment: Same with the randomly happen. This only happens to me after reinstalling windows 10 yesterday, and my experience with it before that was normal.

Comment: By reinstalling Windows you might have brought it to the same level as mine. I don't know of a way to fix it. You could signal the bug to Microsoft via the Feedback Hub. In the meantime, you could use Chrome which is very similar but doesn't have this bug.